# mysql LAST_INSERT_ID with parameter sequence implementation

Tags: mysql, multithreading, innodb

While creating threadsafe sequence in mysql, I came across mysql documentation - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id, suggesting to create sequence like this -

```
1. mysql> CREATE TABLE sequence (id INT NOT NULL);
2. mysql> INSERT INTO sequence VALUES (0);
3. mysql> UPDATE sequence SET id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id+1);
4. mysql> SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

My question is instead of step 4, why can't i query sequence table directly to get the id every time i need to fetch a new id? Like this - SELECT id FROM sequence; Is there any downside of directly querying the sequence table vs LAST_INSERT_ID as suggested in docs?

My mysql implementation looks like this -

```
CREATE TABLE sequence (id INT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO sequence VALUES (0);



 DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE nextVal(OUT nextval INT)
   BEGIN
   UPDATE sequence SET id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id+1);
   SELECT id into nextval FROM sequence;
   END //
 DELIMITER ;
```

And to generate new id, i can use this

```
   call nextVal(@output1);
   select @output1;
```

Edit1: Updating sequence creation process, to be lock free, after talking to all folks that replied. I have also made the table more generic to accommodate multiple sequences in single table and used function instead of procedure

```
 CREATE TABLE sequences (
  name CHAR(20),
  id BIGINT DEFAULT 1,
  increment TINYINT,
  UNIQUE KEY(name)
);


/* Call nextval('seqname'), and it returns the next value. */
/* If the named sequence does not yet exist, it is created with initial value 1 and increment 1 */
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION nextval (seqname CHAR(20))
RETURNS BIGINT
BEGIN
INSERT INTO sequences(name,id,increment) VALUES (seqname,LAST_INSERT_ID(1),1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id+increment);
RETURN LAST_INSERT_ID();
END
//


/* Testing */
SELECT nextval('seq1');
SELECT nextval('seq2');
insert into sequences(name,id,increment) values ('seq3', 1000, 5);
SELECT nextval('seq3');
```

Comment: "While creating threadsafe sequence in mysql" Why the trouble?? `AUTO_INCREMENT` option in MySQL is threadsafe.

Comment: You realize your code is entirely wrong? `AUTO_INCREMENT` is not a sequence, using it to implement something that must be sequential is horribly wrong. `AUTO_INCREMENT` is made to be **unique** - NOT **sequential** and it uses sequential increment, but it allows for gaps. A true sequence does not allow the gap. Also, as Raymond wrote - `AUTO_INCREMENT` is threadsafe. What problem are you solving?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I need to create oracle like sequence in mysql. For legacy purposes, i need to use the auto generated id without actually inserting the row. The only way to do it is if i can get the next value from sequence. AUTO_INCREMENT is the only way mysql supports sequence but it does not allow to just get the next integer.

Comment: The code MySQL documentation provides looks to be correct to simulate oracle like sequence..  Also "Is there any downside of directly querying the sequence table vs LAST_INSERT_ID" to "anwser" that `LAST_INSERT_ID()`  is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis.  This behavior ensures that each client can retrieve its own ID without concern for the activity of other clients, and without the need for locks or transactions.

Comment: Thanks. Please check the updated solution in the edited post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your procedure won't work if another client runs it at the same time, because they're both updating the same row of the `sequence` table. You'd need to run both the `UPDATE` and `SELECT` in a transaction to prevent overlap.

`LAST_INSERT_ID()` is managed on a per-connection basis, so each client gets their own sequence, without having to lock each other out with transactions.

Comment: Thanks for your input.. Yes one option could be to use "Select for update" so that row is locked when updated. Better option could be to use `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` instead of `SELECT id into nextval FROM sequence`. That way row lock wont be necessary. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: `select for update` is only useful if the select is *before* the update, not after. Also, this table only has one row, so there's no difference between locking the row and locking the whole table. `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` avoids the whole problem by not referring to the table at all.

Comment: Thanks. Please check the updated solution in the edited post